# Routing of react-router appends route to current route instead of going to the route only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing

First of all, I want you to inform that I'm using [`react-boilerplate`](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate) for this app. So you should be aware that the way routes are declared there are somewhat [dynamic](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/blob/master/docs/js/routing.md). the way it is similar [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/DynamicRouting.md) in the docs of `react-router`.

So here's the problem, I have three user roles, codenamed **DP**, **PT**, and **OP**. Each has a different navigation sidebar, screens to be shown, and permissions etc.
But as requested by the client, setting aside the backend and/or API, I must first show the created screens for each user roles that I developed.

So I created a route pattern similar to this:

- `/dp/dashboard`
- `/dp/manage`
- `/dp/info`
- `/pt/dashboard`
- `/pt/info/share`
- `/op/dashboard`
- `/op/financial`

^  Assuming these are **some** of the navigation items, as you can see, some items are available to **ALL** or **SOME** user roles, some are exclusive to **ONE** user and so on.

So in my implementation, I created a login where I set a state in the redux store of the current user role, i.e. `userRole: DP`, then in my `Home`, I generate the navigation items depending on the state of the `userRole`.

The items on those navigation items are also passed an `href` or a `Link`'s `to` attribute, somewhat like `href={'/'+this.state.userRole.toLowerCase()+'/some/route'}`, resulting into the similar routes above.

Now the problem is, with all that in set, whenever I try to navigate to an inner sub navigation item, it works fine.

`/pt/info/share`

But if I click to a `Financial` navigation item, it goes like this:

`/pt/info/pt/financial`

Why is that? What is the true nature of `react-router`, and what is the workaround so that I could achieve the above routes?

PS. I also tried removing the part of "appending the `'/'+this.state.userRole.toLowerCase()`" or the `/pt` etc., but it works fine, 
it does not append whatsoever to the current route when navigating between navigation items, just `/financial`, `/dashboard`, not `/financial/dashboard`.

Comment: Why not write the app in a way that each page nows about the role instead of having the role in the URL?